# Serialize Java Exceptions using Jackson

Tags: java, exception, jackson

```
package com.dh.inheritance;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;


public class Client6{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(); 
        objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT);         
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.IS_GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);         
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, true);
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_SELF_REFERENCES, true);

        try {

            String test = null;
            test.length();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            try {
                String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(e);
                System.out.println(jsonString);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }   

}
```

I am getting below exception, when i execute above code.Let me know,How to solve this problem.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: java.lang.NullPointerException["cause"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:230)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:879)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:666)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:678)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeWithType(BeanSerializerBase.java:569)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.TypeWrappedSerializer.serialize(TypeWrappedSerializer.java:32)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3613)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2980)
    at com.dh.inheritance.Client6.main(Client6.java:33)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446891/jackson-self-reference-leading-to-cycle

Comment: Stefen Thanks for reply. Let me try as you said.

Answer (score 1):

It is working below code for writing as json string.

objectMapper.registerModule(new MyModule());

```
package com.dh.inheritance;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;


public abstract class MixIn {

    @JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.StringIdGenerator.class, property="$id")
    private Throwable cause;

}

package com.dh.inheritance;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.Version;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

public class MyModule extends SimpleModule{

    public MyModule() {
        super("test", new Version(2, 7, 2, null));
    }

    @Override
    public void setupModule(SetupContext context) {
        context.setMixInAnnotations(Throwable.class, MixIn.class);      
    }

}
```

But reading json to Object got failed.
Output:

> {"java.lang.NullPointerException":{"detailMessage":null,"cause":{"java.lang.NullPointerException":{"$id":"912da540-bf85-4e5d-869c-acfaebe85bdf","detailMessage":null,"cause":"912da540-bf85-4e5d-869c-acfaebe85bdf","stackTrace":null}},"stackTrace":null}}
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "$id" (class java.lang.NullPointerException), not
>   marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "cause", "stackTrace",
>   "detailMessage"])  at [Source:
>   {"java.lang.NullPointerException":{"detailMessage":null,"cause":{"java.lang.NullPointerException":{"$id":"912da540-bf85-4e5d-869c-acfaebe85bdf","detailMessage":null,"cause":"912da540-bf85-4e5d-869c-acfaebe85bdf","stackTrace":null}},"stackTrace":null}}; line: 1, column: 107] (through reference chain:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException["$id"])    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:62)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:855)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1083)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1389)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ThrowableDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(ThrowableDeserializer.java:135)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:115)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:49)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1017)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:488)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.ThrowableDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(ThrowableDeserializer.java:104)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:133)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:115)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:49)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1017)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:42)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3789)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2779)
>     at com.dh.inheritance.Client6.main(Client6.java:45)